# Quarkus 0.20.0: maven settings-security.xml mandatory to run tests?

Tags: quarkus

I am updating the [quarkus-todo-app](https://github.com/cescoffier/quarkus-todo-app) (a demo application) to `0.20.0`.

When I run the tests with:

```
./mvnw clean verify
```

I get this entry in the log:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running io.quarkus.sample.TodoResourceTest
        ℹ︎ Checking the system...
        ✔ Docker version should be at least 1.6.0
        ✔ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jbr/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecUtil.read(SecUtil.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.SecDispatcherImpl.getSec(SecDispatcherImpl.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.SecDispatcherImpl.decrypt(SecDispatcherImpl.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.SettingsDecrypterImpl.decrypt(SettingsDecrypterImpl.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.SettingsDecrypterImpl.decrypt(SettingsDecrypterImpl.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenRepoInitializer.newSession(MavenRepoInitializer.java:207)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenRepoInitializer.newSession(MavenRepoInitializer.java:169)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.<init>(MavenArtifactResolver.java:122)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.<init>(MavenArtifactResolver.java:56)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenArtifactResolver$Builder.build(MavenArtifactResolver.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoaderFactory.newDeploymentClassLoader(BootstrapClassLoaderFactory.java:313)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:311)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:70)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:250)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:249)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jbr/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecUtil.toStream(SecUtil.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecUtil.read(SecUtil.java:56)
    ... 60 more
```

Is this file now mandatory? What should be the content.

I have the feeling that this was not the case with `0.19.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the servers in the Maven settings file is configured with a password which is recognized as encrypted. So it's looking for that additional config file to be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works as expected.

The stacktrace when the file does not exist is ugly. The code should check for the existence of the file before trying accessing it.